# can anyone tell me why the result is 7 7 7 but no 7 7 10?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int *wedgic(int foo)
{
    cout<<foo;
    return (&foo);
}

int main()
{
    int fo=7;
    int *blah;
    blah=wedgic(fo);
    (*blah)+=3;
    wedgic(fo);
}
```

can anyone tell me why the result is 7 7 7
but no 7 7 10??

please help, I guess I dont understand what does Blah=wedgic(fo); do...

thanks

Comment: This program makes only *two* attempts to output anyhting. It cannot possibly output *three* numbers. Neither `7 7 7` nor `7 7 10` is possible. Either your code is fake, or your claim about its output is false.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your function `wedgic` returns a pointer to its local variable `foo`. The pointer becomes invalid immediately after the function `wedgic` terminates. Any attempts to use the returned pointer value lead to undefined behavior. In other words, you program produces no meaningful results. The behavior is undefined. Whatever you see there (`7 7 7` or whatever else) is just an accident with no meaningful explanation.

Secondly, your program make only *two* attempts to output anything. Yet you claim that it somehow outputted *three* numbers. This is highly unlikely, even for a program with undefined behavior. It is either that your claim about the output is false, or you posted fake code. When you ask question about the results produced by some code, please, post real code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `wedgic()` returns a pointer to its own local variable rather than the address of `fo` you declared in `main()`.

The variable `foo` in `wedgic()` is a non-static local variable which means its lifetime does not extend beyond a call to this function. Returning a pointer to such a variable is just plain wrong since as soon as the pointer is used outside the function the thing it points to no longer exists.

Thus

```
(*blah)+=3;
```

is ineffective and in fact dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explaination!!